# I am looking to flip a div to do a 360 rotation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a `div` with class `square` and inside it, I have a `div` with class `circle`. The square has `position: absolute` and circle has `position: relative`. Also the circle is centered relative to the square `div`. But when I am rotating the circle using `rotate`, the circle loses it's center position and goes to somewhere random.

HTML

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="circle">
    Dark
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.circle{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all 0.6s linear;
}

.square{
  width:120px;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all 0.6s linear;
}

.circle:hover{
  transform:rotateZ(200deg);
}

.square:hover{
  transform:rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

Can you guys tell me how to solve this issue and why is this behaving this way? I want to know about the problem and what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Please provide a snippet code with preview for better response. But referencing to your explanation, you need to add "transform-origin: center;" to add rotation origin to the center of your element and not top left as default

Comment: here is the link for codepen

https://codepen.io/eeemons/pen/MWXorjj

Comment: You can look at the circle at the pen it rotates how ever it goes to the bottom for some reason. I want the circle to be at the place where it is now and only rotate 200deg. If that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you change `transform`, keep the previous states of the element like here:

```
.circle:hover{
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotateY(200deg);
}
```

Otherwise, translate will change top (0,0) as default.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the reason. Now I understood.

Comment: @MaksudulHaque if the answer is correct to you, please vote +1